# How to save file in assets so it can be properly loaded in Android Studio?

Tags: android, libgdx, filenotfoundexception, runtimeexception, file-not-found

I am following a guide on creating a replica of Flappy Bird. - http://www.kilobolt.com/day-6-adding-graphics---welcome-to-the-necropolis.html

The step I am having trouble is loading the texture from the assets directory. There are the author's instructions on how to do this.
[image]

And the code that he uses to actually load the texture

```
        texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/texture.png"));
```

My file structure looks like this(I am using Android Studio 1.0 while the author is using eclipse) [image]

I had to manually create the data directory inside the assets folder. However when I try to run the application, I get these exceptions

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load file: data/texture.png
Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: File not found: data\texture.png (Internal)
```

Does anyone know what the issue is? The texture.png is clearly inside the data directory of assets. I also made sure to clean the project right after copying the .png file into the data directory as the author mentioned.(so resources can be properly loaded). Is the issue just that were using two different IDES, so that different method calls have to be made?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to run Desktop app. Since `assets` is located in android project you have to explicitly set working directory for Desktop project. Go to `Edit Configurations...`, choose desktop configuration and set `Working directory` to path to android assets folder. Something like:
[image]

Comment: thank you :) Is there a reason why the author didn't do this in eclipse?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anything about the guide or Eclipse :)